# Typing in proper way objects as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently I have the following component

**SearchButton.tsx**

```
export interface Props {
  // some other props
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

export const SearchButton: React.SFC<Props> = ({
  // other props
  onClick,
})
```

**Popover.tsx**

```
interface ButtonComponentProps {
  onClick: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

interface Props {
  buttonComponent: React.ComponentType<ButtonComponentProps>;
}

class FilterPopover extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    render() {
        const {buttonComponent: BtnComponent} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                //...
                <BtnComponent onClick={this.open} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**Page.tsx**

```
<Popover buttonComponent={SearchButton}/>
```

But I have a mistmatch between types:

```
The expected type comes from property 'buttonComponent' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Popover> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<Props>'
```

So if I change the props from `Popover.tsx`

```
interface ButtonComponentProps {
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}
```

then interfaces match, but how Typescript is inferring this type through `SearchButton`? Is it ok to match interfaces in that way? Why those ones should be the same?

> React 16.4.1 Typescript 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is comparing the type of `SearchButton`, which is `React.SFC</*SearchButton*/ Props>`, to the type of the `buttonComponent` prop of `FilterPopover`, which is `React.ComponentType<ButtonComponentProps>`.  Looking at [the definition of `React.ComponentType<P>`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/812734a111bf54e268766f32761335f3b9a062c2/types/react/index.d.ts#L53), one alternative is `React.StatelessComponent<P>`, which is another name for `React.SFC<P>`.  `React.SFC<P>` is invariant in `P`, meaning that the types substituted for `P` (`SearchButton` `Props` and `ButtonComponentProps`) must match exactly.

You might think a component that accepts an optional prop `onClick` should be usable in place of a component that accepts a required prop, because it just means that the optional property will always be set.  However, this isn't the case because of the way [the optional `propTypes` and `defaultProps` fields of a stateless component](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/812734a111bf54e268766f32761335f3b9a062c2/types/react/index.d.ts#L344-L346) have been declared.  I'm not familiar with the detailed rationale behind the design of the type declarations.  The easiest thing would be to just match your props interfaces exactly.